# Replace successive end lines using Groovy

Tags: java, regex, string, groovy, replace

I have the following regex to replace successive end lines with nothing:

Example :

[image]

```
line.replaceAll("\\R+$","");
```

this is my java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "si vous me permettez de parler une seconde";
        line.replaceAll("\\R+$", "");
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

That's work well, but I need to develop it in groovy:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "si vous me permettez de parler une seconde";
        line.replaceAll("\\R+\$", "");
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

But the groovy regex doesn't replace the end lines with nothing, so at the end I get the same String.

I didn't understand why, any ideas?

Comment: You need to assign the new value to `line`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Put that as the answer, and I'll vote it up :-D